# OpenLayers read / write GeoJSON

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

i try to store features of a OpenLayers Map Layer to a database and therefore I try to write the features objects into a GeoJSON object. But I get an `Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined` error when I try to read the object. Here what i tried:

```
       const testFeature = new Feature({
          geometry: new Point([0, 0]),
          name: 'Test Point '
        });
        const geoJsonObject = new GeoJSON();
        geoJsonObject.writeFeaturesObject(testFeature);
        console.log(geoJsonObject);

        const importObject = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJsonObject);
        console.log(importObject);
```

The first log of the "geoJsonObject":

```
{
  "dataProjection": {
    "code_": "EPSG:4326",
    "units_": "degrees",
    "extent_": [
      -180,
      -90,
      180,
      90
    ],
    "worldExtent_": [
      -180,
      -90,
      180,
      90
    ],
    "axisOrientation_": "neu",
    "global_": true,
    "canWrapX_": true,
    "defaultTileGrid_": null,
    "metersPerUnit_": 111319.49079327358
  },
  "defaultFeatureProjection": null
}
```

Here the error from the log of the importObject:

```
Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined
```

OpenLayers Version: 6.2.1
Docs: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_GeoJSON-GeoJSON.html#writeFeature

Thanks!

Comment: can you try to write and read any simple feature in an array? Like [new Feature(new Circle([5e6, 7e6], 1e6))]?

Comment: Thanks for your comment – i have edited the questions  and yes the same error

Comment: You can compare your code with an example:https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html

Comment: you should either call writeFeatureObject if you pass a single feature or writeFeaturesObject and pass [testFeature] to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as needing an array of features with writeFeaturesObject your use of geoJsonObject was wrong

```
const geoJsonObject = new GeoJSON().writeFeaturesObject([testFeature]);
console.log(geoJsonObject);

const importObject = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJsonObject);
console.log(importObject);
```